# Is this the correct formulation for the universal property and pushout diagram for cokernel?

Tags: category-theory, definition, universal-property, morphism

The following question is taken from $\textit{Handbook of Mathematics}$ by Thierry Vialar,page 608

I consulted the Vialar's handbook and hoping to see what the dual formulation of cokernel in terms of pushout diagram look like. Vialar had the definition of Kernel in terms of pullback diagram and also description of its universal property.  For cokernel, he only has the pushout diagram along with the text "In a category with a terminal object $1$.  The cokernel of a morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ is the pushout $\text{cokernel}(f)$ in".  For both pullback and pushout diagrams, I appended the maps identities:  $K\xrightarrow{} 0\xrightarrow{} B  =K\xrightarrow{p} A\xrightarrow{f} B$ and $A\xrightarrow{f} B\xrightarrow{i} \text{coker}(f)  =A\xrightarrow{} 1\xrightarrow{} \text{coker}(f).$ I also appended diagrams (1') and (2'), both of which included labeled edges.

Definition of Kernel

In a category with an initial object $0$ and pullbacks, the kernel (denote $\text{ker}(f)$) of a morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ is the pullback $\text{ker}(f)\rightarrow A$ along $f$ of the unique morphism $0\rightarrow B$

$(1)$$\quad$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} \text{Ker}(f)=K & \xrightarrow{} & 0\\
\quad\small {p}\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow\small {}  &  \\
\quad A & \xrightarrow{f} & B 
\end{array}$ $K\xrightarrow{} 0\xrightarrow{} B  =K\xrightarrow{p} A\xrightarrow{f} B$ $\quad$ $(1')$$\quad\quad$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} \text{Ker}(f)=K & \xrightarrow{h_1} & 0\\
\quad\small {p}\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow\small {h_2}  &  \\
\quad A & \xrightarrow{f} & B 
\end{array}$ $h_2\circ h_1=f\circ p$

This determined the object $\text{ker}(f)$ as the object (unique up to unique isomorphism) for which the following universal property holds:  "$\textit{for any object }$ $C$ $\textit{and any morphism }$ $s:C\rightarrow A$ $\textit{such that }$ $f\circ s=0$ $\textit{is the zero morphism, there is a unique morphism }$ $\psi:C\rightarrow \text{ker}(f)$ $\textit{such that }$ $s=p\circ \psi.$

Definition of Cokernel

In a category with a terminal object $1$.  The cokernel of a morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ is the pushout $\text{cokernel}(f)$ in

$(2)$$\quad\quad$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} A & \xrightarrow{f} & B\\
\quad\small {}\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow\small {i}  &  \\
\quad 1 & \xrightarrow{} & \text{coker}(f)
\end{array}\\ $ 
$A\xrightarrow{f} B\xrightarrow{i} \text{coKer}(f)  =A\xrightarrow{} 1\xrightarrow{} \text{coKer}(f)$

$(2')$$\quad\quad$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} A & \xrightarrow{f} & B\\
\quad\small {z_1}\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow\small {i}  &  \\
\quad 1 & \xrightarrow{z_2} & \text{coker}(f)
\end{array}$ $i\circ f=z_2\circ z_1$

This determined the object $\text{coker}(f)$ as the object (unique up to unique isomorphism) for which the following universal property holds: "$\textit{for any object }$ $C'$ $\textit{and any morphism }$ $w:B\rightarrow C'$ $\textit{such that }$ $w\circ f=0$ $\textit{is the zero morphism, there is a unique morphism }$ $\phi:\text{coker}(f)\rightarrow C'$ $\textit{such that }$ $w=\phi\circ i.$

Question:  Is the corresponding description of the universal property for cokernel formulated correctly?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes it is. See for example Coequalizers in III.3. (6)  "Categories for the Working Mathematician" by MacLane and replace one of the two arrows by the zero arrow.

Comment: @linkja sorry which two arrows I am supposed to replace by the zero arrow. Also what is a zero arrow?

Comment: I meant in the reference. And with zero arrow I just mean your arrow "through" your 1. And I just noticed that in the reference cokernel is also defined just above in (5)

Comment: @linkja ok ok thank you for your comments and also for the reference.  I will go check Categories.

Comment: I guess the original statement for the assumes that $0$ is both initial and terminal (which is what zero objects means). A morphism $f\colon X\to Y$ is then a zero morphism if it factors through $0$  as the composition of the maps $X\to 0$ and $0\to Y$.